# Iterate two maps using stream

Tags: java

I have two maps with the same size but the type of their values are different.
Now I need to iterate them and generate new map.
I tried stream but the `Map.Entry` cannot be resolved. I'm using JDK 11;

```java
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> consumerGroupOffsets = getConsumerGroupOffsets(groupId);
Map<TopicPartition, Long> topicEndOffsets = getTopicEndOffsets(groupId, consumerGroupOffsets.keySet());
Map<Object, Object> consumerGroupLag = consumerGroupOffsets.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entry -> mapEntry(entry.getKey(), new OffsetAndLag(topicEndOffsets.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue().offset())))
```

Comment: `.map()` is not meant to create a map but to map one type to another. This would return a stream and thus could not be assigned to `Map<Object, Object>`. What you probably want is `collect(Collectors.toMap(...))`. Also is `mapEntry()` meant to be a static method? If not then it's obvious why this can't be resolved: you're not calling it on any instance. Besides that you should not need it since  `Collectors.toMap(...)` should handle creating the map entries for you.

Comment: i need to return Map<Topicpartition, OffsetAndLag>

Comment: Well, that might be the case but your code contains `Map<Object, Object> consumerGroupLag = <some stream>.map(...);` which I was commenting on. What types you're using depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little confusing where the lag is coming from since it appears you are retrieving offsets only.

But this is how it would be structured to get the long values regardless of what they are called (I guessed at the constructor for the `OffsetAndLag` class)

```
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> consumerGroupOffsets = ...;
Map<TopicPartition, Long> topicEndOffsets = ...;
```

- Use the key from `consumerGroupOffsets` for the target key.
- use that key to retrieve the lag (or offset) from `topicEndOffsets`
- use the value for that key (which should be `OffsetAndMetadata`) to get the offset (or lag)

```
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndLag> consumerGroupLag =
        consumerGroupOffsets.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                        entry -> new OffsetAndLag(
                                topicEndOffsets
                                        .get(entry.getKey()),
                                entry.getValue().offset())));
```

Expected `OffsetAndLag` class (or something similar)

```
static class OffsetAndLag {
    public long offset;
    public long lag;
    public OffsetAndLag(long offset, long lag) {
        this.offset = offset;
        this.lag = lag;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you i think that is useful, but "Entry::getKey" not accepted in my IDE Non static mehode cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: That is simply a method reference and should not have anything to do with your context.  In fact it worked for me in **any** context.  What IDE do you use?  Did you import Map.Entry?  And you might try changing it to `entry->entry.getValue()`.